# Model Derivative API 404 reply

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have some fairly large refit files uploaded to BIM360. When trying to use `GET :urn/metadata/:guid` on the 3D modelview in the file, I get a 404 reply. For the 2D views in the same file I do not have any issues.

I tried with both force-get and x-ads-force without any luck.

Using same code I do not have any issues with other files (both revit and non-refit files)

Are there any known issue with large revit-files in the translation to SVF? Any ideas to something I could test to see if it is the file or my code that has the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As an extra comment: I have now checked some more large revit file, and seem to be experiencing this for them all. So it seems it might be something in the handling of the large amount of data.

Comment: diagnostics code: 
diagnostic: 'Failed to query the data.'

Comment: For large models, please use SVF https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format

Comment: So I have to start a job converting them back to SVF since I can already see in the manifest that they have "overrideOutputType: 'svf2'" - correct? And this job will not take cloud credits?

Comment: it will take cloud credits, sorry we can't undo(or in this case reuse) the already translated consumption.

Comment: I did a test with a single translation and see if I could access the data, but I get the same error, and therefore not a solution to my current issue.

Comment: approximate file size?

Comment: 450 mb - but with a lot of repetitive geometry.